# vba-Como nomear automaticamente os pdf gerados

Tags: vba, pdf, microsoft-word

qual alteração eu devo fazer nessa macro para ele nomear os arquivos gerados de acordo com a coluna nomes da mala direta

```
Sub SalvaParesFolhasEmPDFs()
  Const Caminho = "D:\POLÍCIA CIVIL MS\Acadepol 2020\Curso de Formação\Certificados\Certificados pdf"
  Dim i As Long, NúmPágs As Long
  NúmPágs = ThisDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
  For i = 1 To NúmPágs Step 2
     ThisDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=Caminho & "Arquivo " & (i \ 2 + 1), _
                                      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                      Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=i, To:=i - (i <> NúmPágs)
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Salve, Paulo! Tentei até te ajudar, mas realmente são necessários os detalhes. O nome do arquivo é passado no parâmetro ```OutputFileName```, mas qual é o nome que você quer? Como o software vai descobrir qual é a correspondência entre uma coluna da mala direta e o nome do arquivo? Esses PDFs são gerados por essa mala direta? Se for o caso, seria importante dar um exemplo da planilha da mala direta com dados fictícios, mas os cabeçalhos reais.

Answer (score -2):

Paulo, você pode usar a instrução Name
Ex.:

```
Dim Caminho1 AS String
Dim Caminho2 AS String

Caminho1 = "D:\POLÍCIA CIVIL MS\Acadepol 2020\Curso de Formação\Certificados\Certificados.pdf"

Caminho2 = "D:\POLÍCIA CIVIL MS\Acadepol 2020\Curso de Formação\Certificados\CertificadoGerado.pdf"

Name Caminho1 AS Caminho2
```

No exemplo ele muda o nome Certificados.pdf para CertificadoGerado.pdf na mesma pasta. Se você não informar o caminho completo, ele pode mover o arquivo de pasta.
Não sei se expliquei bem.